# When does $f^{-1}=\frac{1}{f}$ with $f$ a function mapping $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, analytic-functions, tag-removed

[In mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function), an inverse function is a function that "reverses" another function: if the function $f$ applied to an input $x$ gives a result of $y$, then applying its inverse function $g$ to $y$ gives the result $x$, and vice versa. i.e., $f(x) = y$ if and only if $g(y) = x$ , i'm interesting to check the relationship between multiplicative inverse  function and the inverse compositional function ,Then my question here is related to the solution of the below functional equation

> > **Question:**
> >      When does  $ \displaystyle f^{-1}=\frac{1}{f}$  with $f$ a function mapping $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ ?
> >
> > **Note:** $f^{-1}$ is the compostional inverse of $f$ and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{f}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $f$
> >
> > **Edit:** I have edited the question to define $f$ according to the answer below by Robert Israel.

Comment: Your edit fails to dispense with Robert Israel's counterexample.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260278/

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585394

Comment: [I have edited the question .../... Robert Israel.]---> then you should better put $f:\mathbb{R}^*\to \mathbb{R}^*$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have  $f^{-1}(x) = 1/f(x)$ with both sides defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  Namely, if $t = f^{-1}(0)$ then $f^{-1}(t) = 1/f(t) = 1/0$ is undefined.

EDIT:
With the correction that $f$ maps $\mathbb R^* = \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$ to itself, here is one class of solutions.  Take any $f_0$ that maps $(0,1]$ one-to-one onto $(-\infty,-1]$ with $f_0(1) = -1$.  Then let
$$ f(x) = \cases{f_0(x) & if $x \in (0,1]$\cr
                 1/f_0(1/x) & if $x \in (1,\infty)$\cr
                f_0^{-1}(1/x) & if $x \in (-1,0)$\cr
                 1/f_0^{-1}(x) & if $x \in (-\infty,-1]$\cr} $$

Comment: For example, $f_0(x)=-1+\tan\left(\frac{(x-1)\pi}2\right)$.

Answer (score 7):

You may like to look into the following [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2687332.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Robert Anschuetz II and H. Sherwood, *When Is a Function's Inverse Equal to Its Reciprocal?* The College Mathematics Journal
Vol. 27, No. 5 (Nov., 1996), pp. 388-393.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik If only there were some sort of **sci**entific **hub** where many behind-a-paywall papers were available.  (It has this paper!)

Comment: Thanks for this orientation , really i have checked bookzz.org but i don't find it  available

Comment: This is freely and legitimately available on Jstor.

Comment: @MattF. only if you sign up, which means it's not really _freely_ available. But I get your point.

Answer (score 6):

You can download a copy of my University of Central Florida thesis that covers this topic in even greater detail than the Journal article below:

http://stars.library.ucf.edu/rtd/3139/

Robert Anschuetz

Comment: Thanks , your paper is already montioned and cited above by the answer of T. Amdeberhan